SOLVED! TypeError: MeComCommon._set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
I am struggling with error, mentioned in title.
That's the function I am calling:
    @classmethod
    def set_parameter(self, value, parameter_name=None, parameter_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Set the new value of a parameter given by name or id.
        Returns success.
        :param value:
        :param parameter_name:
        :param parameter_id:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return: bool
        """
        # get the query object
        vs = self._set(value=value, parameter_id=parameter_id, parameter_name=parameter_name, *args, **kwargs)

        # check if value setting has succeeded
        #
        # Not necessary as we get an acknowledge response or Value is out of range
        # exception when an invalid value was passed. 
        # current implementation also often fails due to rounding, e.g. setting 1.0
        # but returning 0.999755859375 when performing a self.get_parameter
        # value_set = self.get_parameter(parameter_id=parameter_id, parameter_name=parameter_name, *args, **kwargs)

        # return True if we got an ACK
        return type(vs.RESPONSE) == ACK

That's how I call it:
mcc = mecom.MeComCommon()
mcc.set_parameter(value=-40, parameter_id=3000)

and that's what I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\THERMAL ELEPHANT V3 TEST JIG\Python Script\main.py", line 189, in <module>
    mcc.set_parameter(value=-40, parameter_id=3000)
  File "C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\THERMAL ELEPHANT V3 TEST JIG\Python Script\mecom\mecom.py", line 659, in set_parameter
    vs = self._set(value=value, parameter_id=parameter_id, parameter_name=parameter_name, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: MeComCommon._set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'


I tried things mentioned here: https://dev.to/lavary/about-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self-in-python-2i36
But it is no use. So I hope, that somebody will help me. :)

I believe that the problem is that _set is an instance method, while set_parameter is a class method.
Try removing the @classmethod decorator.

Now I get
AttributeError: 'MeComCommon' object has no attribute '_execute'

I can't tell you what went wrong there. It seems like a different error, you didn't send the full error message, and we are reaching the point that it is just a regular debugging, stack overflow isn't great for that.
If you want to link to a github repo so I can see the full code, I can look there.
